# Installing Ubuntu on desktop creates an error. Please help!

Tags: system-installation, usb

I am trying to install Ubuntu on a desktop via a USB that was set up with UNetbootin on a Mac OS-X and I am getting these error messages on a black screen:

> error: cannot read the linux header
>   error: you need to install the kernel first
>   invalid image

What is going on here?